# SELECT query to filter records using optional user-supplied parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am writing a procedure to fatch record from database table based on filter condition. Now as user may apply filter or may not. So based on that filter criteria will get applied.

i.e. If filter parameter will contain any value than only it will apply condition not.

**Note:** I can achieve it through *if.. else.. condition* and execute different query altogether separately to get my desire output. But what I am trying to ask is, is there any better approach for it rather than if.. else..

**Example** ( here i_status_id, i_category_id may contain any value or may not)

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `FilterRecord`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `FilterRecord`(IN i_status_id BIGINT,IN i_category_id BIGINT)
BEGIN  
    SELECT 
            Item_backlog.backlog_id AS backlog_id,
            Item_backlog.title AS backlog_name,
            Item_backlog_Group.title AS group_Name,
            Item_backlog.description AS description,
            Item_backlog.est_start_date AS estimated_start_date,
            Item_backlog.est_end_date AS estimated_end_date,
            Item_backlog.actual_start_date AS actual_start_date,
            Item_backlog.actual_end_date AS actual_end_date,
            Item_backlog.estimated_hours AS estimated_hours,
            Item_backlog.actual_hours AS actual_hours,
            Item_backlog.status_id AS status_id,
            APV_Status.name AS status_name ,
            Item_backlog.priority_id AS priority_id,
            APV_Priority.name AS priority_name,
            Item_backlog.rank AS rank,
            Item_backlog.isActive AS isActive,
            Item_backlog.created_by_id AS created_by_id,
            Item_backlog.created_on AS created_on,
            Item_backlog.modified_by_id AS modified_by_id,
            Item_backlog.modified_on AS modified_on
        FROM 
            Item_backlog 
        INNER JOIN     
            ApplicationParamValue AS APV_Status ON (Item_backlog.status_id=APV_Status.appParamValueId)
        INNER JOIN    
            ApplicationParamValue AS APV_Priority ON (Item_backlog.Priority_Id=APV_Priority.appParamValueId)
        INNER JOIN 
            Item_backlog_group AS Item_backlog_Group ON (Item_backlog.backlog_group_id=Item_backlog_Group.backlog_group_id)
        WHERE 
            Item_backlog.status_id=i_status_id
        AND
            Item_backlog.category_id=i_category_id

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below it will apply filter criteria based on parameter passed:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `FilterRecord`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `FilterRecord`(IN i_status_id BIGINT,IN i_category_id BIGINT)
BEGIN  

    DECLARE Var_status_id VARCHAR(200);
    DECLARE Var_category_id VARCHAR(200);
DECLARE andCondition VARCHAR(200);


    IF i_status_id<>0 THEN 
        SET Var_status_id=CONCAT(' (Item_backlog.status_id = ', i_status_id,')');
        SET andCondition ='AND';
    ELSE 
        SET Var_status_id="";
        SET andCondition ='';
    END IF;


    IF i_category_id<>0 THEN 
        SET Var_category_id=CONCAT(andCondition,' (Item_artifact_category_mapping.category_id = ', i_category_id,')');
    ELSE 
        SET Var_category_id="";
    END IF;


    SET @SQL := CONCAT('SELECT 
            Item_backlog.backlog_id AS backlog_id,
            Item_backlog.title AS backlog_name,
            Item_backlog_Group.title AS group_Name,
            Item_backlog.description AS description,
            Item_backlog.est_start_date AS estimated_start_date,
            Item_backlog.est_end_date AS estimated_end_date,
            Item_backlog.actual_start_date AS actual_start_date,
            Item_backlog.actual_end_date AS actual_end_date,
            Item_backlog.estimated_hours AS estimated_hours,
            Item_backlog.actual_hours AS actual_hours,
            Item_backlog.status_id AS status_id,
            APV_Status.name AS status_name ,
            Item_backlog.priority_id AS priority_id,
            APV_Priority.name AS priority_name,
            Item_backlog.rank AS rank,
            Item_backlog.isActive AS isActive,
            Item_backlog.created_by_id AS created_by_id,
            Item_backlog.created_on AS created_on,
            Item_backlog.modified_by_id AS modified_by_id,
            Item_backlog.modified_on AS modified_on
        FROM 
            Item_backlog 
        INNER JOIN     
            ApplicationParamValue AS APV_Status ON (Item_backlog.status_id=APV_Status.appParamValueId)
        INNER JOIN    
            ApplicationParamValue AS APV_Priority ON (Item_backlog.Priority_Id=APV_Priority.appParamValueId)
        INNER JOIN 
            Item_backlog_group AS Item_backlog_Group ON (Item_backlog.backlog_group_id=Item_backlog_Group.backlog_group_id)
        WHERE', Var_status_id, Var_category_id);

        PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL; 
        EXECUTE stmt;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a defined value for indicating when a parameter is not specified (e.g. I've used `NULL` below to indicate that the parameter is not supplied), what you can do is the following to apply the parameter conditionally.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `FilterRecord`(IN i_status_id BIGINT,IN i_category_id BIGINT)
BEGIN  
    SELECT 
            Item_backlog.backlog_id AS backlog_id,
            -- ...
        FROM 
            Item_backlog 
        INNER JOIN     
           -- ..
        WHERE 
            (Item_backlog.status_id=i_status_id OR i_status_id IS NULL)
        AND
            (Item_backlog.category_id=i_category_id OR i_category_id IS NULL);
END
```

Note however that the performance of doing this can be degraded.

[SqlFiddle example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45be6/1) - I've assumed MySql, btw, as per your primary tag and backticks.

Comment: I already tried this approach, it will not work.. as OR looks for 2nd half of condition if 1st half is FALSE right ? But even if filter criteria doesn't contain any value than also it is not looking for second half of your mentioned OR part i.e. in either case Item_backlog.status_id=i_status_id it return true only

Comment: I'm not understanding you correctly. Can you add a small truth table for the inputs `i_status_id` and `i_category_id` on a small table (possibly use my SqlFiddle) and what the expected results are? Thanks

Comment: @ChandanPrakashSharma I'm pretty sure the answer you accepted does the same thing as mine (albeit using zero, not null as the default value), although note that in the other answer, that if both inputs are defaulted, that the query will crash because of a trailing `WHERE`.

Comment: Hey @Stuart you are right, I missed one thing the WHERE clause also I need to put inside IF..ELSE.. block to add it dynamically based on filter criteria exist. Thanks buddy